# Create dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by, extract

So I have this dataset which has 64 variables. I would like to make 3 seperate dataframes grouped by 'Region' which has 3 categories. At the same time I want to extract its corresponding rows with their Date (date) and Temperature (num).

Is it possible to do this somehow? I had tried searching the internet but have trouble understanding the process.

Comment: It is much easier to answers, if you provide your data. It could also be only a few rows, and for that, you can use function `dput()`. In addition, post your current code,

Answer (score 1):

One solution, if I understand correctly, would be to use `split` and `map`. This example uses `iris` and splits the data.frame into a list based on `species` and selects columns.

It would be helpful if you provided a reproducible example next time.

```
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)

iris %>% 
    split(.$Species) %>%  
    map(~.x %>% select(c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)))
```

If you want to filter rows, then you could do this:

```
iris %>% 
    split(.$Species) %>%  
    map(~.x %>% filter(Petal.Width > 1 & Sepal.Width>2))
```